# Check checkbox based on ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a form with many checkboxes of this kind :

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="user_ids_for_edit" name="user_ids_for_edit[]" data-toggle="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" value="14">Billy Joel
</label>
```

The form is part of a modal.

When the modal loads, I run an ajax query to check the checkboxes, based on the result of the ajax query :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/data/team_users",
   data: { id: data.id },
   cache: false,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(response)
      {
        for (var user in response) {
            alert(response[user].id); // this gives the right user id, so my ajax call works... 
            $('#user_ids_for_edit[value="'+ response[user].id +'"]').attr('checked', true);
        }

      }
});
```

Unfortunatelly, the relevant checkboxes don't get checked. I don't know how to progress further. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you check like this? $('#user_ids_for_edit').val(response[user].id).attr('checked', true);

Comment: if you have multiple check box then each one should have same name but different id ,you code is not working because your all element (checkbox) have the save id

Comment: While it is correct that since 1.6 you should use `prop()` your code should work fine even when using `attr()` It works fine in a snippet to test. Also, while you are having multiple elements with the same identifier, which is terrible design, again, your code works fine in a snippet and all checkboxes with the same identifier will get checked as you are using attribute selectors along with the identifiers. https://jsfiddle.net/gwuoyoxv/

Comment: Thanks. I just made the ids unique. and tried the suggest prop instead of attr. However, the checkboxes still don't get checked.

Comment: @AdamDulson As I said and have shown in a js fiddle, your code works just fine, even if not adhering to standard but either way the issue seems to be something else

Comment: The form is part of a modal. And I'm trying to check the boxes in the success section of an ajax call... Would any of these mak a difference ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead of attr

```
prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: While `prop` is preferred, `attr` will work just the same and is not the source of the issue.